# jupyter-server keeps asking for token login

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-server

Ι have set up a jupyter server instance on kubernetes. The login prompt screen is the following

[image]

I exec into the pod, run `jupyter notebook list`, and in the two boxes at the bottom of the screenshot I enter the token returned by the above command and a password.

I then log in, log out and I am prompted **again** with the same screen

When I insert the password / token I created in the previous step in the `Password or token` field at the top of the screen, I get an invalid credentials response.

How can I set up a password-only authentication?

The links in the screenshot point to 404 pages.

```
jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.4
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.18.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
jupyter lab      : 2.2.8
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.7
traitlets        : 5.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter has been updated to notebook 7. Maybe you should update it and check if it solves your problem.